# PHP Dynamic Dropdown HTML menus parsing in to a second Dynamic menu issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been been trying to build a dynamic menu that passes in to another menu, like the old [COUNTRY] >> [CITIES] scenario but not what I am exactly doing.

But from what I have followed I seem to have an error somewhere. I can see the dropdown menus. First saying [Loading...] and second saying [Select Part Number]

So from what I can see it is getting stuck at the pulling info from the 1form.php file so I have been looking at this for a couple of days and am no further forward, can someone explain what I have done wrong here please.

NB: Negativity doesn't help people learn!

```
1form.php
-------------
<?php
include 'process/database.php';
include 'header.php'; // this includes the session_start();
//if ($_SESSION == false) {
//    header('location: login.php?status=notloggedin');
//}


$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `custcode` ORDER BY `ID2` ASC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'ID1'       => $row['ID1'],
            'ID2'       => $row['ID2'],
            'ENABLED2'  => $row['ENABLED2'],
            'SOLDTO2'   => $row['SOLDTO2']
        );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>



2form.php
-------------
<?php
include 'process/database.php';
include 'header.php'; // this includes the session_start();
//if ($_SESSION == false) {
//    header('location: login.php?status=notloggedin');
//}


$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM partnumbers WHERE ID1='".$_GET["ID1"]."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id'            => $row['id'],
            'partnumber'    => $row['partnumber'],
            'disabled1'     => $row['disabled1'],
            'tiedto'        => $row['tiedto']
        );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>


3form.php where it should take place
----------------------------------------
<?php
include 'process/database.php';
include 'header.php';
//if ($_SESSION == false) {
//    header('location: login.php?status=notloggedin');
//}
?>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

        function customer(){
    $('#firstDDLModel').empty();
    $('#firstDDLModel').append("<option>Loading......</option>");
    $('#secondDDLModel').append("<option value='0'>--Select Part Number--</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"1form.php",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#firstDDLModel').empty();
            $('#firstDDLModel').append("<option value='0'>--Select Customer--</option>");
            $.each(data,function(i,item) {
                $('#firstDDLModel').append('<option value="'+ data[i].ID1 +'">'+ data[i].ID1+'</option>');
            });            
        },
        complete: function() {
        }
    });
}

function part(ID1){
    $('#secondDDLModel').empty();
    $('#secondDDLModel').append("<option>Loading......</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"2form.php?ID1="+ID1,
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#secondDLModel').empty();
            $('#secondDDLModel').append("<option value='0'>--Select Customer--</option>");
            $.each(data,function(i,item) {
                $('#secondDDLModel').append('<option value="'+ data[i].ID1 +'">'+ data[i].partnumber+'</option>');
            });            
        },
        complete: function() {
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    customer();
    $("#firstDDLModel").change(function() {
        var ID1 = $("#firstDDLModel").val();
        part(ID1);
    });
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <span>Customer</span>
    <select id="firstDDLModel"></select>
    <span>Part</span>
    <select id="secondDDLModel"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

and my DB in basic form is

```
CUSTCODE
+-----+------+-----------+----------+
| ID1 | ID2  |  SOLDTO2  | ENABLED2 |
+-----+------+-----------+----------+
|  5  | AA01 | Mr Smith  | 0        |
|  6  | DF06 | Mrs Jones | 0        |
+-----+------+-----------+----------+

PARTNUMBERS
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  ID   | partnumber | partdesc  | disabled1 | ID1 (fk custcode:ID1) |
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  101  | Part001    | a shoe    | 0         | 5                     |
|  102  | Part030    | a dog     | 0         | 6                     |
+-------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: _"First saying [Loading...]"_ - so that obviously means, that the success callback of your AJAX request did not execute at all - if it did, then the first line `$('#firstDDLModel').empty();` would have seen to it, that you _don't_ see that `[Loading...]` option any more. So go and check how that request actually got answered, using your browser dev tools.

Comment: Incidentally your code is wide open to sql injection - use `prepared statement` rather than embedding variables in the sql like that. Also - why so many different endpoint scripts - a single script can handle all the ajax requests if setup properly which would make maintenance easier.

Comment: I am completely new to this, and make no hidden fact of this. This currently sits on a non-web facing desktop with xampp etc. I only got in to PHP a few weeks ago and never seen ajax before. If there is a simpler way that what Ive done I would be elated to learn how. I know my SQL is bad and that is on my to do list after this and a couple more tasks.
I am now googling how to find ajax errors with dev tools and it says go in to dev tools networking XHR and there is nothing in there that is sticking out. On the ajax entry i get a green dot and 200 on the status. TIA

Comment: Without much work we cannot test your code. It is easy enough to mock up the above into a PHP page but with no db and no data it means we would not see possible errors for ourselves. Putting your code into a snippet here all I see is the preflight request failing ( of course ). I don't use jQuery but I would remove `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",` from the ajax request and also ` dataType:"json",` I would also add an `error` function to the ajax requests to see what is happening perhaps?!

Comment: Your PHP is using `$_GET["ID1"]` in the SQL yet your AJAX requests are sending POST requests

Comment: Can you share some images of what you want exactly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had another look at your code, created a couple of test tables in the database and tried to get your code working.

The ajax requests are sending POST requests but your PHP is looking for a GET variable when it constructs the 2nd dropdown menu. The ajax request also featured `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"` which was causing ( for me ) the requests to fail completely so these were removed and a `data` parameter used instead of the querystring.

Given a test schema like this:

```
mysql> describe custcode;
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID1      | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ID2      | varchar(6)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SOLDTO2  | varchar(32)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ENABLED2 | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from custcode;
+-----+------+-----------+----------+
| ID1 | ID2  | SOLDTO2   | ENABLED2 |
+-----+------+-----------+----------+
|   1 | aa01 | mr smith  |        1 |
|   2 | fd83 | mrs smith |        0 |
+-----+------+-----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)




mysql> describe partnumbers;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PARTNUMBER | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| PARTDESC   | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| DISABLED1  | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| ID1        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from partnumbers;
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+-----+
| ID  | PARTNUMBER | PARTDESC | DISABLED1 | ID1 |
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+-----+
| 101 | part001    | a shoe   |         0 |   1 |
| 102 | part002    | turtle   |         1 |   2 |
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And modified PHP/HTML & Javascript

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    /* 
        Include database connection.
        Obviously this will be different for you.
    */
    chdir('../../dbo');
    require 'db-conn-details.php';
    require 'mysqli-conn.php';
    
    
    
    /*
        Process POST requests made by AJAX calls.
        Rather than multiple files, a single script is used
        to process all requests.
        
        Also, a `Prepared Statement` is used to mitigate SQL injection
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'] ) ){
        
        $args=array();
        
        switch( $_POST['action'] ){
            case 'fetch-customer':
                $sql='SELECT * FROM `custcode` ORDER BY `ID2` ASC';
            break;
            case 'fetch-part':
                $sql='SELECT * FROM partnumbers WHERE ID1=?';
                $args[]=$_POST['id'];
            break;
        }
        
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        if( !empty( $args )){
            $types=str_repeat( 's', count( $args ) );
            $stmt->bind_param( $types,...$args );
        }
        
        $stmt->execute();
        $res=$stmt->get_result()->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $res ) );
    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
        <span>Customer</span>
        <select id="firstDDLModel"></select>
        <span>Part</span>
        <select id="secondDDLModel"></select>
        
        
        <script>
            function customer() {
              $('#firstDDLModel').empty();
              $('#firstDDLModel').append("<option>Loading......</option>");
              $('#secondDDLModel').append("<option value='0'>--Select Part Number--</option>");
              /*
                POST requests do NOT send data in the querystring
                but rather it is within the body so use the `data`
                argument for the ajax request as below.
                
                The "action" parameter allows the PHP to differentiate
                the request and process the appropriate SQL query.
              */
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: location.href,
                data:{ 
                    action:'fetch-customer'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  $('#firstDDLModel').empty();
                  $('#firstDDLModel').append("<option value='0'>--Select Customer--</option>");
                  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    $('#firstDDLModel').append('<option value="' + data[i].ID1 + '">' + data[i].ID1 + '</option>');
                  });
                },
                complete:()=>console.log('ok'),
                error:(err)=>alert(err)
              });
            }

            function part(ID1) {
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: location.href,
                data:{ 
                    action:'fetch-part',
                    id:ID1 
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  $('#secondDLModel').empty();
                  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    $('#secondDDLModel').append('<option value="' + data[i].ID1 + '">' + data[i].PARTNUMBER + '</option>');
                  });
                },
                complete:()=>console.log('ok'),
                error:(err)=>alert(err)
              });
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
              customer();
              $("#firstDDLModel").change(function() {
                var ID1 = $("#firstDDLModel").val();
                part(ID1);
              });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```